# Which adjectives can describe verbs?

Tags: adjectives

Certain nouns can also be verbs, i.e. `run` or `play`. Some adjectives can be applied to both forms of such a word, by switching the positioning:

> - Run fast
> - Fast run
> - Play clean
> - Clean play

But this isn't always possible -- `Play seriously` vs `serious play` -- the adjective changes its form.
What is the name for this? I'm looking for a list of adjectives that go after a verb.

P.S.
The tag "adjectives" claims that adjectives are only applied to nouns.

Comment: Actually, *play clean* is also incorrect, along with *play serious*.

Comment: i obviously have no idea what i'm talking about

Comment: But you're learning, and that is as much as anyone can ask for.

Comment: "play serious" would be an ungrammatical slang form;  it's common enough in spoken language, but is largely restricted to commands between team-mates who don't have time to bother with five- or ten-word constructions.

Comment: These "adjectives" are usually called "[flat adverbs](http://grammar.quickanddirtytips.com/do-all-adverbs-end-in-ly.aspx)". There are a lot of them; they're used more in American English than in British English, and more in the South than in the rest of the U.S. However, they're not an American innovation—they were common in British English in Shakespeare's time.

Comment: Can someone tell me which obscure or hard-to-understand reason is in play here when an answer was given and selected? Thank you for your help...

Comment: Most nouns can be adjectives. English Parts of Speech are not constant. Any English word can be used in any part of speech (with some minor exceptions), so be very careful with proposed "grammar rules" that tell you what **can't** be done because something "is an adjective" or "isn't a verb" or the like. You want it to be an adverb, just treat it like one and everybody will get it and go on. Actual English speakers pay no attention to things like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference between *serious* and *seriously* is that the former is an adjective, while the latter is an adverb.  We use adverbs to modify verbs (hence *Play seriously* = *[Verb] [adverb]*), but adjectives to modify nouns (hence *Serious play* = *[Adjective] [noun]*).  Since *[fast](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/fast)* is both an adjective and an adverb, *run fast* and *fast run* are both correct.

It would be erroneous to suppose that adjectives can be applied to verbs.  In the first of your examples, though *fast* is correct as an adjective, it is also correct as an adverb. The second example is fallacious since *clean* is not an adverb, making *play clean* incorrect.

As to the list, what you would end up finding would be adjectives which are also adverbs, such as *fast*, since that type of word is the only type which can modify both nouns and verbs.  *Clean*, as before stated, would not be on the list.

Also, the tag is correct.  Adjectives modify nouns, and adverbs modify verbs.

Comment: What's wrong with *play clean*? Isn't it like *play nice* or its opposite, *play dirty*?

Comment: They are colloquialisms, and technically incorrect as long as *clean*, *nice*, and *dirty* are not adverbs.

Comment: Being inappropriate for a formal register (for example, you would not usually write *play clean* in a research paper) doesn't make something that occurs in the speech of native speakers *incorrect*. Many dictionaries list words like [clean](http://www.oxfordadvancedlearnersdictionary.com/dictionary/clean_3) as adverbs and note how they're used. The OP makes a good point, too: *play serious* is probably more likely to be ungrammatical than, for example, *play dirty* (see [COCA summary](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/?c=coca&q=11697068)); maybe because *seriously* has currency compared to *dirtily*.

Comment: I'm sure that's also how *fast* got to be where it is; *fastly* must never have caught on.  Also, the dictionary there says *clean* as an adverb is "informal" (what I'm calling "colloquial") and even that definition wouldn't fit with *play clean*, anyhow.  In fact, that definition is useful enough that I would say it *was* correct, when used like that (e.g. *I got clean away*).  Also, *playing dirty* is an idiom for *foul play*; it would never be used of a child playing in the dirt.  IOW, In all those usages, the adjective used as an adverb has a different meaning than when it has an -ly.

Comment: So *dirty* as an adverb has a different meaning from *dirtily* as an adverb.  *Playing dirty* doesn't equal *playing dirtily*, etc.

Comment: The [OED entry for *clean* as an adverb](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/34055) dates from 1000 AD, where it says: “This sense naturally arose from the consideration that when a substance is taken entirely out of any vessel, etc., without leaving a particle behind, the vessel is left clean, and its cleanness is a measure of the completeness of the removal. Hence clean was naturally used with all verbs of taking, driving, or going away, of losing, and thence of finishing up, completing, or performing any action.”

Answer (score 1):

The fact is, "adjectives" can **never** modify verbs. The only thing that modifies verbs, are adverbs.

In your example "run fast", "fast" is an adverb, not an adjective:

> [fast :](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fast#Adverb) quickly, with great speed; within a short time

When you switch "Run Fast" to "Fast Run",  "Run" becomes a noun, and "fast" is legitimately an adjective:

> A regular trip or route. / A trial of an experiment. ("Fast run" meaning a fast(adjective) trip or trial, etc.)

The fact is, whenever you switch the words around (Play clean/Clean play; Play seriously/Serious play), the modifiers(*Serious* and *Clean*) change from an **adverb** to an **adjective**

Comment: I think you missed the point of the question, and are letting descriptors distort your view of English topology.  When native speakers learn "a fast run" and "run fast", they do not first learn "adj" and "adv".

All grammatical categories have been imposed on the spoken language after-the-fact, and so, when the topology of the language indicates that certain words can indeed be used to modify either verbs or nouns, there's not any point in insisting that this description doesn't "fit" with established grammatical descriptors.    To do so is to miss an opportunity for study and learning.

Answer (score 1):

Though adjectives, most often, describe nouns, they can also be used as a complement to (not a description of) linking verbs or the verbs of being, [to be] verbs, (am, is, are, was, were).

"That cow sure is **happy**."

"It smells **gross** in the locker room."

(Paraphrased, in part, from [Grammarly](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/adjective/#:%7E:text=Most%20students%20learn%20that%20adjectives,or%20adverbs%20or%20other%20adjectives.&text=But%20adjectives%20can%20do%20more,or%20the%20verb%20to%20be)).